# Three equations and three unknowns involving calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, vectors

The following is an abstract from my book:

[image]
[image]

It gives only "one" solution for the components of $C$. I can't imagine any other solution. If exists, can somebody show me any other solution for the components of $C$?

Also how do we know how many solutions exist? Is it just like $-$ three unknowns and three equations. Hence one solution....?

Comment: One other solution is to add a constant to each component of $C$; all the derivatives (which is all you care about) will still be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Assume a scalar function $f$ which is smooth enough, what can you say about $$\nabla \times (C+\nabla f)=\nabla\times C+\nabla\times\nabla f?$$

Comment: I see.................